# Question about electric vector potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, potential

$$\vec{E}=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{Q\vec{e_r}}{r^2}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{\vec{e_\theta}\times\vec{e_\phi}}{r^2}=\frac{Q\sin{\theta}}{4\pi\epsilon_0}[\frac{\vec{e_\theta}}{r}\times\frac{\vec{e_\phi}}{r\sin{\theta}}]$$
So, we have
$$\vec{E}=\frac{Q\sin{\theta}}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\nabla{\theta}\times\nabla\phi=-\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\nabla{\cos{\theta}}\times\nabla\phi=-\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\nabla\times(\cos{\theta}\nabla\phi).$$
From the definition of vector potential, we can define
$$\vec{A}=-\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\cos{\theta}\nabla\phi$$ 
as the vector potential for electric field. 
I wanna know is it correct? And can I find a vector potential for electric field?

Comment: The first two = are wrong. Are you sure you want a vector pointing in the theta direction?

Comment: I think this question should be reopened. Unless I'm mistaken, the OP has chanced upon some interesting and subtle features of the dirac delta function directly from Coulomb's law. Consequently, the attached answer is incomplete. He seems to have made a good faith attempt to gain ground on the issue. I think discussing the DD in this context would be very worthwhile.

Comment: The time derivative of the magnetic potential contributes to the electric field. The Lorentz gauge also allows for some modifications to electric and magnetic potentials that can conceal time dependence, useful in some quantum mechanics problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your derivation is correct.But $\vec A$ is not a vector potential.
In your derivation the electrical charge $Q$ is a constant.However, in general,
the charge distributes in the space.
If $\vec E=\nabla\times\vec A$, then$\nabla\cdot\vec E=0$. By Maxwell equations, there is not charge distributing in space at all .It is in contradiction with fact.Thus there doesn't exist vector petential for electric field.